# How to correctly close a console application using the youtube-dl process to download Twitch stream whenever I want

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, console-application, youtube-dl

The test program has the following code:

```
string url = "https://www.twitch.tv/ricoy";
string outputPath = @"D:\ruta_del_archivo_salida.mp4";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "youtube-dl",
    Arguments = $"-f best -o \"{outputPath}\" \"{url}\"",
    //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    //var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    //process.WaitForExit();

    Console.Read();
    KillProcessAndChildren(process.Id);
}

static void KillProcessAndChildren(int pid)
{
    // Cannot close 'system idle process'.
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
            ("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid);
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        KillProcessAndChildren(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));
    }
    try
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        proc.Kill();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // Process already exited.
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I press de key in the console the youtube-dl process gets kill and also de ffmpeg but the file is left with .part extension and does not work.

I was expecting the code to left a .mp4 file but for reason it does not.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that you kill the process without checking that's done!

Comment: @Romylussone hello, yes I know, but that's what I want, if you run that command in the cmd console and press ctrl+c you can cancel the program whenever you want and it still finishes correctly.

Comment: ok did you try without the KillProcess instruction, and did it do the job properly, if its this case you must think of a way to kill the process after the download is done?

Comment: yes, I have tried and it still doesn't do what I want, I think the problem is that I am not killing the process gracefully, because I don't know how to kill a nowindow process gracefully.